# Python Selenium webdriver: Does not detect Alert generated nor gives Error

Tags: python, testing, automation, selenium-webdriver, alert

*I am doing Test-Case Automation of WebPage using Selenium Webdriver in Python.
*I need to verify the Alert Message generated on Webpage.
*Using Webdriver When I try to handle the Alert, It says no Alert found.Even It does not give any error message(Like Unexcepted Alert generated) if I dont handle the Alert.
*Please suggest , Why Webdriver is not detecting Alert.

```
Code:

from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class Tcgr1(unittest.TestCase):  
    def setUp(self):  
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()                             
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)   
        self.base_url = "https://colama5863.co5863domain.net/infracc/app/Workspace#VMs"
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_tcgr1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Settings").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Group Mgmt").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), \"Create\")]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("groupname").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("groupname").send_keys("tcgr1_group")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[2]/span/button[contains(text(), \"Create\")]").click()
        for i in range(60):
            try:
                if self.is_alert_present(): break
            except: pass
            time.sleep(1)
        else: self.fail("time out")
        self.assertEqual("Group created successfully", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":     
   unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using. Are you using implicit wait functions or the more reliable expected conditions wait functions?

Comment: Please give some suggestions... I have added Code of test-case.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver is working as expected. The **NoAlertPresentException raises when doing an action over an unexisting alert window**. It doesn't raise when you switch to an unexisting alert window.

So your code for being functional needs an action on the supposed alert:

```
def is_alert_present(self):
    try: 
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()  # this doesn't raise Exception
        alert.text  # this DOES RISE Exception if there isn't an alert
        return True

    except NoAlertPresentException:
        return False
```